# Is it a bad practice to use a single column table with a nominal value as PK?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When dealing with No-SQL databases, this would not be a problem as a relation would not make sense (or at least would be unnecessary), but when the infrastructure does not support No-SQL databases, scenarios such as creating tags for articles would raise some concerns (from the perspective of finding the best practice).

Assuming that I have three tables as `Articles`, `Tags`, `ArticleTags`. In this case, the `Tag` names must be unique as duplicate tags in the `Tags` table would not make any sense. Taking this into the account, I can do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [Tags](
     [TagId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGRIDCOL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
     [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
```

And this approach can be considered as a standard practice. However, since the `Tags.Name` is unique, I can also use the `Name` column as the primary key and remove the `TagId` column. The question is that, if I do this and use the `Tags.Name` as the primary key, even the `Tags` table would be considered as redundant and I can simply add a new column such as `Tag` in the `ArticleTags` table without any relation and this will be ok if we want to allow users to generate new tags when necessary (losing the FK constraint).

However, would this violate the normalization rules? and would this be a better practice in comparison with the standard approach (having both id and name)?

Comment: The advantage of a separate table would be that if you have 1,000,000 articles with the same tag storing a million ints in the junction table might be much more compact than the string 1 million times. And if you rename a tag you only need to update 1 row not a million.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Yes that is true.

Comment: is not a bad practice  .is commen ..  is one of the pattern for normalization  ..

Comment: Also would you not have any metadata about a tag such as created date or created by?

Comment: @MartinSmith: Actually no. The tags in this scenario would be used for SEO optimization and searching features. So it would not be really needed to track dates and creators (in contrast with the use of tags in StackOverflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a rather bad idea to have a GUID as a primary (there might be exceptions).  If you have a table where you are going to be doing frequent inserts, then a GUID as a primary key is definitely a bad idea.

Why?  Well, by default, the primary key is clustered in SQL Server.  You *can* override this, but let's stick with the default.

Because the GUID can have a smaller value, this results in inserts going between existing rows.  That tends to cause fragmentation and (much) slower inserts.

Note that this even occurs with `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`.  As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql) explains:

> After restarting Windows, the GUID can start again from a lower range,
>   but is still globally unique.

If you are doing all the inserts at once, then it doesn't matter, much.

However, this seems so much simpler:

```
CREATE TABLE [Tags](
     [TagId] int identity(1, 1) primary key,
     [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Here are some reasons:

- Identity columns take up less space (ints are smaller than GUIDs).
- Identity columns are much handier for referring tables (foreign keys take up less space).
- Integer ids are easier for people to recognize when looking at the data or typing in an id (say for debugging).
- Inserts always go at the end of the table.

I would just avoid the habit of ever using GUIDs (or UUIDs in other databases) as primary keys.  The one case where I've had to relax this is when I generate data using SparkSQL or BigQuery.  However, I consider it a bug in those tools that they cannot readily do `row_number()` on a large data set.

As for using `Name`, I would discourage that.  You might want to rename a tag at some point in the future or decide that 50 characters is not large enough.  Although you can have cascading foreign key references, I think a unique integer id is a safer approach.  In addition, the id gives some inadvertent information -- such as the last tag inserted into the table.